# How can I dockerize Apache ZooKeeper with seed data inserted?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, dockerfile

I'd like to run Apache Zookeeper using Docker, with seed data inserted (for testing configuration). I tried using startup script like followings:

Dockerfile

```
FROM zookeeper:latest

ADD startup.sh .
EXPOSE 2181
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

./bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 create /foo ""
./bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 create /foo/bar ""

./bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
```

But this didn't work, since I tried to insert data before the server's up and running.

How can I dockerize ZooKeeper server which has seed data on startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage `docker-compose` for this.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
   zookeeper:
     image: zookeeper:latest
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "2181:2181"
   zookeeper_setup:
     image: zookeeper:latest
     depends_on:
       - zookeeper
     links:
       - zookeeper
     command: sh /setup/startup.sh
     volumes:
       - ./:/setup
```

> Make sure you remove `./bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground` from `startup.sh` and replace `localhost` with `zookeeper` in `startup.sh`.

Then just run `docker-compose up` so it will first start `zookeeper` service and then it will run `zookeeper_setup` service with modified command. (make sure you mount directory with `startup.sh` properly in `zookeerper_setup` service)

If `zookeeper` needs more time to bootup, you can add `sleep 5` (or more) in `startup.sh`.

Next time, when you don't need to configure it again with `startup.sh`, you can run `docker-compose up zookeeper` to start pre-configured `zookeeper` service.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and probably simpler) approach is to start zookeeper in the background, create your nodes, stop zookeeper and then run it in foreground mode.

Your `startup.sh` could be something like -

```
./bin/zkServer.sh start
./bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 create /foo ""
./bin/zkServer.sh stop
echo "Starting Zookeeper in foreground mode..."
./bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
```